# Flutter - Token error on publishing package update

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

I'm trying to update my package on pub.dev, I suddenly start getting this message which i didnt get before

```
https://pub.flutter-io.cn package repository requested authentication! You can provide credential using:
    pub token add https://pub.flutter-io.cn
```

I tried running :

```
dart pub token add https://pub.flutter-io.cn
```

which will be successful. But if i try running the publish command again

```
dart pub publish
```

I get :

```
Invalid token for https://pub.flutter-io.cn deleted.
https://pub.flutter-io.cn package repository requested authentication! You can provide credential using:
    pub token add https://pub.flutter-io.cn
```

I'm actually stuck here.

NB: My package repo is public and I've also added it(as token) but didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that because of https://pub.flutter-io.cn,
*so upload to https://pub.dartlang.org*

---

```
 dart pub publish --server=https://pub.dartlang.org
```

---

https://pub.flutter-io.cn  URI, I think for china so check your pc where from coming.

---

### [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445016/error-in-publishing-package-pub-finished-with-exit-code-1)

---