# Unable to sign into https://pub.flutter-io.cn for authentication

Tags: flutter, authentication, package, pub.dev

Unable to sign into 'https://pub.flutter-io.cn'. The user clicks on 'Sign in' don't register.

Note, I am in China and can sign into pub.dev with a VPN no problem. But in order to publish a package I am asked to sign in to https://pub.flutter-io.cn.

I have turned on/off ad blocker (and VPN) and tried on Firefox, Edge and Chrome, refreshed etc, so appears a China-related issue.

How can I get around this? E.g. is it possible to change the settings so Flutter publishes to pub.dev where my account is linked, instead of https://pub.flutter-io.cn.?

```
Uploading...
https://pub.flutter-io.cn package repository requested authentication!
You can provide credentials using:
    flutter pub token add https://pub.flutter-io.cn

Authentication is required, please add `authorization` header.
Authentication failed!
pub finished with exit code 65
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution thanks to this post [Flutter - Token error on publishing package update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70729709/flutter-token-error-on-publishing-package-update)

Either

1. Delete environment variable PUB_HOSTED_URL
   https://pub.flutter-io.cn (easiest way).
2. Or run in the terminal:

```
 dart pub publish --server=https://pub.dartlang.org
```